# push files into git remote repo using different user account

Tags: git, github, ssh

I want to push my code changes to git remote repo, I am able to pull changes but it is not allowing me to push the changes.
I am using ssh key authentication for authorization, the keys are generated using my email id. But the windows system where I am doing development is a admin account. I have kept the required private public key into .ssh folder but since the windows user is different than the account using which I configured key it is giving **pre-receive hook declined** error. I have tried by setting the user name and user email same as the account used for key gen using **git config** command, but not luck so far. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it from Eclipse. Configured the ssh key path in network setting and then to commit code using my account, first add the untracked files to git index and then you would be able to see those file in Git Staging view. There it will show your staged changes and you enter commit message, then there will be author and committer by default it will be having the value of whichever user account you have logged in like in my case it was admin account, but I changed it to my account manually and then do commit and push. Doing this I was able to push the code to repository successfully.

```
Author abc<abc.@mail.com>
Committer abc<abc.@mail.com>
```

Comment: you can add these entries even in git configuration by going into Window>>Preferences and there filter with git and go to configuration then add user.name and use.email with appropriate values.